# Inferring a particular set is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was given in my homework the following question:

Suppose that for some set A, the well ordered set P(A) (under inclusion) has the property that every non-empty subset of it has a minimal element. I was asked to show that A is finite.

I'd be happy to get clues/hints in this manner

Comment: Saying that "$P(A)$ has the property that every non-empty subset of it has a minimal element" is the same as saying that $P(A)$ is well-ordered (as a partial order). So you could more simply say "Suppose that for some set $A$, the *partially ordered* set $P(A)$ (under inclusion) is well-ordered."

Comment: @AlexKruckman In the usual terminology, a well-ordered set must be **totally** ordered. If every nonempty subset of $P$ has a **least** element then $P$ is well-ordered. A partially ordered set in which every nonempty subset has a **minimal** element is called **well-founded** not well-ordered. If $A$ has more than one element, then the power set $P(A)$ is not well-ordered.

Comment: @bof Sure, that's why I wrote "well-ordered (as a partial order)". But you're right, well-founded is a better choice. In any case, the term "well-ordered" is out of place where it appears in the OP's question, which is the point I was trying to get across.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oops, I didn't even see "well ordered" in the original post.

Comment: @AlexKruckman "well-founded" not well-ordered.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume for a contradiction that $A$ is infinite, then the set of all infinite subsets of $A$ is nonempty, and therefore has a minimal element. That is, there is an infinite set $B\subseteq A$ such that every proper subset of $B$ is finite. Can you get a contradiction from that?

Comment: Does the following use the axiom of choice: let b be an element of B, then B\{b} is finite and hence has the same cardinality as Nn, for some natural n, but then B has the same cardinality as N(n+1) and hence finite.

Comment: @availanche No, it doesn't use the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction, A is infinite.

Define B to be the set of all sets of A (or equivalently elements of P(A)) that are infinite.
In this case, A is an element of B, and hence B is non-empty subset of A, and therefore it has a minial element, let it be C.

C is a minimal element of B (by inclusion), hence it does not properly include any set in B, but then it does not properly include any infinite set, i.e. C is an infinite set of A that properly includes only finite sets of A.

Let c be an element in C, then C properly includes C\{c} and hence C\{c} is finite, i.e. shares the same cardinality with Nn, for some natural n, but then C shares the same cardinality with N(n+1) and hence finite, arriving at contradiction.